# Calling private method in ApplicationController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am confused on how this library works:

The ApplicationController has a private method called `selected_account()` as you can see here: [ApplicationController](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/blob/master/adwords_api/examples/adwords_on_rails/app/controllers/application_controller.rb)

Then, from [another Controller](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/blob/master/adwords_api/examples/adwords_on_rails/app/controllers/account_controller.rb) which is a child from ApplicationController, we do an action that does this:

```
 def index()
    @selected_account = selected_account
    graph = get_accounts_graph()
    @accounts = Account.get_accounts_map(graph)
  end
```

How can we do that? Isn't it out of scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be confusing for those who come from java or c# world. But here is a decent explanation

> In Ruby, the inheritance hierarchy or the package/module don't really
>   enter into the equation, it is rather all about which object is the
>   receiver of a particular method call. When a method is declared
>   private in Ruby, it means this method can never be called with an
>   explicit receiver. Any time we're able to call a private method with
>   an implicit receiver it will always succeed. This means we can call a
>   private method from within a class it is declared in as well as all
>   subclasses of this class

Answer (score 2):

It might be confusing at first, but in Ruby `private` does not mean what it means in Java/C++. Ancestors can call private methods just fine.

What `private` actually means is that you cannot call the method with an explicit target. That is, if `foo` is private, you can call it with `foo()`, but not with `self.foo()` or `obj.foo()`. That way you can call private methods only on yourself.

Furthermore, Ruby has `protected`. The semantics are again different from Java/C++ – `protected` methods can only be called from instances of the same class. It is rarely used.

Comment: Thank you, the accepted answer went way over my head after years of PHP/Java style class abstraction rules.

Answer (score 0):

The child controller inherits from ApplicationController so it can call internal private methods on itself without issue.  There is no scoping problem.  The subclass inherits all the public/private/protected methods of its super class.